# This user is clearly being a troll

Tags: discussion, specific-question, abuse

If you look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841399/php-form-security-with-referer/) question, you will notice that *every* answer except the 'best-answer' got a downvote from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/users/80243/longpoke) guy. And his comments are particularly annoying - he makes it clear this was deliberate and had nothing to do with the validity of the answers.

What really troubles me is that the 'best-answer' is **COMPLETELY WRONG AND DANGEROUS** and somehow got some upvotes.

<strike>I seriously think that both [The Rook](https://stackoverflow.com/users/183528/the-rook) and [Longpoke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/80243/longpoke) deserve a suspension.</strike>

---

**Update:** Okay, I need to clarify a few things. First off, I was a little too hasty to accuse [The Rook](https://stackoverflow.com/users/183528/the-rook) and [Longpoke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/80243/longpoke) of being trolls. At first I thought they were **intentionally** trying to create trouble - I didn't think they were actually serious. In light of this, I think downvoting instead of a suspension is in order.

**However,** having said that - anyone who posts the following comment:

> -1 to every answer except this

...and proceeds to downvote the other answers without explanation - is a red flag.

Comment: Ah, thanks @Jon. Wasn't sure what tags to put on this question.

Comment: Thank you everyone who downvoted what is clearly a *dangerously* wrong answer.

Comment: He disagrees and goes off to downvote other answers. What's the red flag for ?

Comment: @Ess: The red flag is because he doesn't explain **why** he's downvoting.

Comment: @George - if you take out the red flag for any unexplained downvote you get, you might need time extensions.

Comment: By the way, Evan Carroll is not a troll; he said so himself.

Comment: Actually the comment "-1 to every answer except this" IS an explanation. He is CLEARLY stating that *this* answer is correct and all the other answers are wrong (in his opinion). Which he is perfectly allowed to do on this site. That is not trolling behaviour.

Comment: I think TheRook is certainly one of the more controversial characters. He certainly carries an ego and his actions are sometimes very questionable, such as here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717599

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While I find the behavior of these two users immature and exceptionally arrogant, it is plain wrong of you to say it was done "without explanation". The user downvoted an answer he thought was wrong, explained his opinion in many comments, and added his own answer.
This is more than you expect from the average downvoter.

Comment: That is true now... but you didn't see the post *before* all of this debate took place :)

Answer (score 23):

I see no suspension-worthy behavior in that question. Obviously there is some difference of opinion as to what is safe -- and if Longpoke believes almost all the answers are dangerously wrong, it is his *duty* to downvote them.

If your answer is correct and The Rook's is wrong, I think you would be much better off fleshing out your answer and explaining the truth instead of telling people that they are "on the brink of getting in trouble" and posting on Meta about it.

(If being wrong were grounds for suspension, I'm afraid I wouldn't be here today.)

Comment: Yes, but this looks very intentional. It seems like the user is *trying* to mislead everyone.

Comment: @George This is how the system works. Fortunately, the valid-voters largely out-number the odd-voters who try to make a mess of things. The good answers will naturally rise to the top in the end.

Comment: @Jonathan: Yes, you are right. The wrong answer is sinking down - but it's still the 'best answer'.

Comment: It's not the "best answer" it's simply the "accepted" answer. How many questions have you seen with the  "accepted answer" having only a few votes and other *much* better answers having significantly more? Besides, he's wrong and **anyone** who develops for the web should know better.

Comment: @Josh: Agreed. I put 'best answer' in quotes because it really isn't.

Comment: yeah, I agree. Maybe you're not understanding the question the user asked? Perhaps, the phrasing didn't make sense to you? The question seems legit. Why did you think it was a troll question?

Comment: @mke: Anytime a user announces that he's downvoting all other answers without explanation... methinks a red light goes off.

Comment: @George False downvotes are indeed detrimental to the system, but how is claiming responsibility for the votes a red light that they are false? Why would someone who announces he is downvoting all answers raise more flags than someone who does it *without* announcing it? What aspect of this act is so dangerous?

Answer (score 13):

The answer is not wrong.

You may not *agree* with it, but it is not wrong.

I think before you're so quick to paint with the troll brush you should take a quick look in the mirror at your own behavior.

Comment: Yes, I admit I jumped on him... only because I didn't think **he was actually serious** with his answer. I thought he was just gaming the site. I still say he's wrong, though. The number of upvotes I got should back up that claim...

Comment: @George It's sunday morning and I'm not entirely on top of this but I think The Rook *is* right. That he's showing off a vulnerability issue that he fixed and the department of homeand security... well. But I think the essence of his answer is correct, because CSRF involve "hijacking" *another user's* session and privileges. For a header to be forged, the user would have to be using a maliciously altered browser - and if that is the case, all is lost anyway, and the attacker won't need CSRF to get hold of anything they want.

Comment: @questions it's an interesting question, because the actual risk of using referer (ugh, misspelled forever) is that some proxies *strip it!* You can't always get it, which means you have to be OK with blocking access to these folks along with your CSRF fix. Using a nonce or key does not have this weakness.

Comment: @Jeff yeah, using a one-time token or a flag in the user's session is definitely the way to go for this if you're serving a broad audience. I just meant in the context of the heated discussion, other than I too thought initially, Rook and Longpoke are indeed right: This is one rare occasion where you *can* trust incoming data to fend off an attack. Anyway, it's a really, really interesting topic, great this question came up!

Comment: @George: "The number of upvotes I got should back up that claim..." Do you want me to send you an email every time I see a provably incorrect answer with a lot of upvotes? (Occasionally it's one of my own...) In this case there aren't even that many upvotes - 7, along with 5 downvotes. If you think that "backs up your claim" in any significant way, I've got a bridge to sell you...

Comment: @Jon: There was only one downvote when I wrote that - and I'm beginning to think that the question was misunderstood and needs rewording.

Comment: @George: Even without *any* downvotes, 7 people agreeing with you is hardly overwhelming evidence that you're right. I've seen plenty of incorrect answers with 7 or more upvotes.